# Thymeleaf: cannot pass a predefined value of hidden th:field

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

There is a form with hidden value fields:

```
<input type = "hidden" th:field="*{key}" value="keyapp" />
<input type = "hidden" th:field="*{secret}" value="supersecret" />
```

The problem is that these fields are passed as empty in the controller. Is there a way to pass thymeleaf fields with predefined in HTML values?

Thanks and kind regards,
Deniss

**Updated:**

`th:object` definition:

```
<form th:action="@{..//do-login}" method="POST" modelAttribute="authEntity" th:object="${authEntity}">
```

**AuthEntity class**

```
public class AuthEntity {

    private String key;
    private String secret;
    private String scope;
    private String grantType;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    // getters & setters omitted //
}
```

**Controller class**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/do-login", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public void doLogin(@ModelAttribute("authEntity") final AuthEntity authEntity,
                    final Model model, HttpServletResponse servletResponse,
                    HttpSession httpSession) throws IOException {
    log.info("Application Key: {}, Secret: {}", authEntity.getKey(), authEntity.getSecret());
}
```

Comment: How do you have defined the form? What `th:object` have you defined? And dows this Object have a `key` and a `secret` property? If you have put these values into the ModelMap then you should reference them with `${key}` and `${secret}`

Comment: @ThomasPawlitzki see above post updated. Please also note that all other parameters are passed correctly by just using `th:field`

Comment: Do you set the fields `key` and `secret`? And how do you try to retrieve the values in your MVC Handler?

Comment: @ThomasPawlitzki updated the post again. Please see.

Comment: Are there values in the html sent to the browser? There you should see the hidden fields with value attributes.

Comment: @matthias I've seen that post, I don't think that is my case. I want to pass a static field value from the html into the thymeleaf object model (if that is possible).

Comment: @ThomasPawlitzki I didn't quite understand your question, sorry. Can you clarify?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145635/discussion-between-thomas-pawlitzki-and-deniss-m).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've run into the same problem with hidden inputs and found no solution but, instead of using th:field, setting the 'id' and 'name' property of the field by hand and omitting th:field.

Comment: But is the value passed at all then?

Comment: If you keep the 'value' property, it is passed (works at least for me :)). IIRC everything in a form having a name is passed upon submitting but I might mix up name and id here.

Comment: With spring and thymeleaf? Are u sure?))

Comment: Yes. My code looks like this: <input th:type="hidden" id="user" class="form-control" name="user" th:value="${#authentication.getPrincipal().getId()}" readonly> and it's getting submitted correctly.

Comment: Ahh ok but what if the value is html static?

Comment: You can set a static value with th:value but you can also just use value, both will work fine.

Comment: Yes I also used <input type="hidden" name="apiType" value="API001" id="apiType"> removed th:field from the input tag. now working, thanks